# rotating/Fortune wheel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am making an app in which I have to add the fortune or rotating wheel. After R&D I found this Raywenderlich sample code  [Rotating Wheel](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit)

It is working fine. But I have to change some rotating wheel UI according to my app requirement. There is need of 12 sections. For that I changed the number of sections 12 here

```
   SMRotaryWheel *wheel = [[SMRotaryWheel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)  
                                                    andDelegate:self 
                                                   withSections:12];
```

This is the UI of rotating wheel which I need to add. [image: Rotating UI]

In the given sample code, when wheel stops then the selection area comes under this arrow get select. [image]

Now I want to change the selection area according to my wheel UI which is on the right side. But I am unable to find that code in the given sample. Please help me out If someone has idea about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're asking us to read the code from some tutorial on the web and fix it to your requirements?

Comment: Hey Abizerm.. I am asking if you have an idea about it.. May be some time you have experience of this issue. If you don't .. then no one is forcing you to give the answer or read the tutorial. @Abizern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add new property for this.

```
@interface SMRotaryWheel : UIControl
//...
@property (nonatomic, assign) float selectionAngle;
//...
@end

@implementation SMRotaryWheel
//...

- (void)setSelectionAngle:(float)selectionAngle
{
    _selectionAngle = selectionAngle;
    UIImageView *im = [self getCloveByValue:currentValue];
    im.alpha = minAlphavalue;
    [self endTrackingWithTouch:nil withEvent:nil];
}
- (void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    CGFloat radians = atan2f(container.transform.b, container.transform.a) - _selectionAngle * M_PI / 180;
//...
}
//..
```

And use: `whell.selectionAngle = 90.0;`